# HDFStore updating stored HDF5 python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have two dataframes, `df1` which is stored in a `pd.HDFStore` object and the other which is to be appended to the dataframe.

```
store = pd.HDFStore('dataframe_store.h5')

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((100, 5)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((100, 5)))

store['df1'] = df1
```

Effectively, I would like the end result to be equal to ...

```
store['df1'] = df1.append(df2)
```

I would like to append `df2` to the stored `df1`, rather completely overwrite the `HDFStore` object with a new dataframe.  Is this possible?

Furthermore, when I run the following code I return `ValueError can only append to Tables`... why is this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((1000, 5)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty((1000, 5)))

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

store['df'] = df

store.append('df', df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#table-format) (my emphasis):

> HDFStore supports another PyTables format on disk, the table
>   format. Conceptually a table is shaped very much like a DataFrame, with rows and
>   columns. **A table may be appended to in the same or other sessions**. In addition,
>   delete & query type operations are supported. This format is specified by
>   format='table' or format='t' to append or put or to_hdf
>
> New in version 0.13.
>
> This format can be set as an option as well pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table') to enable put/append/to_hdf to by default store in the table format.

```
In [361]: store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')

In [362]: df1 = df[0:4]

In [363]: df2 = df[4:]

# append data (creates a table automatically)
In [364]: store.append('df', df1)

In [365]: store.append('df', df2)

In [366]: store
Out[366]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5

# select the entire object
In [367]: store.select('df')
Out[367]: 
                   A         B         C
2000-01-01  0.887163  0.859588 -0.636524
2000-01-02  0.015696 -2.242685  1.150036
2000-01-03  0.991946  0.953324 -2.021255
2000-01-04 -0.334077  0.002118  0.405453
2000-01-05  0.289092  1.321158 -1.546906
2000-01-06 -0.202646 -0.655969  0.193421
2000-01-07  0.553439  1.318152 -0.469305
2000-01-08  0.675554 -1.817027 -0.183109

# the type of stored data
In [368]: store.root.df._v_attrs.pandas_type
Out[368]: 'frame_table'
```

> Note: You can also create a table by passing format='table' or format='t' to a put operation.

Comment: I was looking at the docs and was able to figure it out, but if you could elaborate as to why `store.append('df', df2)` returns `ValueError: Can only append to Tables` ... ??

Comment: Your `hdf5` file must be created in the [`table` format](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html#table-format) (as opposed to the [`fixed` format](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/io.html#fixed-format)). Either use `df.to_hdf(filename, 'df', mode='w', format='table')` to create it, or set `pd.set_option('io.hdf.default_format','table')` so that `format='table'` is the default format.